# Java Calendar - Query number of unique dates in an ArrayList

Tags: java, date, arraylist, calendar

I have the follow dates(Date Objects) in an array list that looks like this:

Date: Sun Jan 25 11:45:05 EST 2015

Date: Sun Jan 25 11:46:05 EST 2015

Date: Sun Jan 25 11:47:14 EST 2015

Date: Sat Jan 24 11:48:59 EST 2015

Date: Sat Jan 24 11:50:32 EST 2015

Date: Fri Jan 23 11:52:01 EST 2015

Date: Fri Jan 23 11:53:29 EST 2015

Date: Fri Jan 23 11:55:16 EST 2015

Date: Wed Jan 21 11:58:48 EST 2015

I want to be able to get the count of all the days that equals Jan 25 2015, Jan 23, 2015 and so on and so on. I have to use the year here as well because obviously the years can be different so i just cant look at the month and day. Currently I am using the Calender DAY_OF_YEAR and YEAR.

To makes things more efficient it would be nice to also do this in a loop where as long as I have data in the Arraylist i ask for the first one and say, "find me all the dates with this DAY_OF_YEAR and YEAR", give me the count of that and then remove those, then all over again until the arraylist is empty."

Is there anyway to do this without writing a custom solution?

Comment: "The number of days" seems like an incomplete sentence.  You mean from then until now?

Comment: sorry i meant the 'count of all the days that equals'..so in this small data set i would get 3 for the number of times i see Jan 25 2015, 2 for Jan 24, 2015 and so on...

Comment: Why can't you just loop through the date list and create a count map? For the first occurrence of the date, create a new count map instance with a count of 1. For subsequent occurrences of the date, increment the count.

Comment: because none of the dates would be equal if i am just comparing dates. For example, all the dates on Jan 25 are actually different because of the time. If i did this, i would have just 1 occurrence of every single item because the times are the differentiators.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is JodaTime's [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html).  Convert your list into a list of those then compare for equality.

Comment: does it still work with all of the other Date objects because I have other code, lots of it that cannot be converted to JodaTime..

Comment: Well it's relatively easy to convert back and forth.  There's a `toDate` method: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDate()

Comment: ok . I just thought of another way to possibly handle this. Instead of putting Date objects in my ArrayList, get the day of year and year from each date(using the Calendar object I have been already using), convert each into a string.. then check for occurrences of that string that way using Collection.frequency